# Insert one list fully inside another list in python

Tags: python, list

How do I insert one list fully inside another python list?

```
>>> list_one = [1,2,3]
>>> list_two = [4,5,7]

>>> list_one.insert(2, [2, 3])
>>> list_one
[1, 2, [2, 3], 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

But I want the result to be:

```
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using slice assignment (if you meant `[1,2,4,5,6,3]`):

```
>>> list_one = [1,2,3]
>>> list_two = [4,5,6]
>>> list_one[2:2] = list_two
>>> list_one
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3]
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that was possible! You learn something new everyday...

Comment: @Julien, It's explained in tutorial ( https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists ). I recommend you to read it if you didn't.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you don't want this result `[1,2,4,5,6,3]` instead? If so, try this:

```
list_one[:2]+list_two+list_one[2:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

```
ActivePython 2.7.13.2713 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 18 2017, 15:40:43) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on wi
n32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> list_one = [1,2,3]
>>> list_two = [4,5,7]
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> result = [ elem for elem in chain(list_one[0:2], [2,3], list_one[2:], list_two)]
>>>
>>> result
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7]
>>> result1 = list(chain(list_one[0:2], [2,3], list_one[2:], list_two))
>>> result1
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7]
```

Comment: You can use `list` instead of list comprehension: `list(chain(list_one[0:2], [2,3], list_one[2:], list_two))`

Comment: Yes, We can do that as well.